# How to access more than one file in a directory without knowing the name of each file in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, file-access

I want to access around 5000 files and work on them one by one. Is there any way to access each in succession without hard-coding the name of each file?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow!](https://stackoverflow.com) Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The following example is from this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm).

```
import os, sys

# Open a file
path = "/var/www/html/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

# This would print all the files and directories
for file in dirs:
   print file
```

Answer (score 0):

And if your directory contains parent directories and files, you could use [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) like -

```
# Example taken from os.walk documentation
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print(root, "consumes", end=" ")
    print(sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files), end=" ")
    print("bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files")
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')
```

Or you could use [scandir](https://pypi.org/project/scandir/) -

```
for entry in os.scandir(path):
    ...
```